# Me marca un error en mi visata, dice que la variable row no esta definida, este error me marca cuando no tengo datos en la base de datos

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

```
foreach($data['prestamos'] as $row):
            /*inicia inspeccionar abonos*/
            $prestamos   = $this->prestamosModel->getAbonosPrestamoInicio($row->pr_id_prestamo );
            $suma_prestamos = 0.00;
            if($prestamos){
                foreach($prestamos  as $row2):
                    if($row2->pa_monto>0){
                        $suma_prestamos = $suma_prestamos+$row2->pa_monto;
                    }
                endforeach;
            }
            $row->suma_prestamos = $suma_prestamos;
            endforeach;


        $this->load->view('control/pagina_inicio', $data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar ese error, debes verificar que `$data['prestamos']` no este vacia, agrega esta linea :

```
if (!empty($data['prestamos'])) {
    foreach($data['prestamos'] as $row):
}
```

Comment: ya lo hice pero en la vista sigue marcando este error
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: row

Comment: puedes agregar a tu respuesta, lo que imprime el arreglo `print_r($data['prestamos']);` ???

Comment: ya lo arregle gracias, ahorita voy a revisar que este ete bien, le puse que la variable $row no fuera vacia con el !empty y me soluciono el problema gracias bro por el apoyo

Comment: entonces el problema no era que prestamos no tuviera datos, si no que algunos venian vacios?

Comment: asi es,era como si marca indefinido y por eso no detectaba bien la variable y ya meti datos y todo funciona bien